# Delete all lines containing backslash from text file

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing, sed, text

I have a file that has content like this:

```
apple
b\all
cat
\34
egg
```

I want to remove all lines containing backslashes. I tried using

```
sed '/\/d' pdataf.txt
```

But it didn't work. What should I try?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to escape the backslash (escape the escape!)

```
$ sed '/\\/d' pdataf.txt
apple
cat
egg
```

Answer (score 9):

`grep`, printing all lines that do not have `\`:

```
grep -v '\\' pdataf.txt
```

Similarly `awk`:

```
awk '!/\\/' pdataf.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash (escape character) in order to replace it.
And if your version of sed supports it, the -i (in-place) option will do the edits on your file without you having to provide an intermediate file.
Also, if you use the -i option, note that it accepts a (recommended!) backup file extension, however if you do not provide one, it is useful to precede your sed command with -e to inform sed that you are not using a backup file extension.

Putting it all together:

```
# Run sed to remove lines with backslash in them

$ sed -i -e '/\\/d' pdataf.txt

# Cat your file to confirm edits

$ cat pdataf.txt
apple
cat
egg
```